# Getting a zipped file from the JSON-object in R

Tags: r, json, zip

Using `GET` I download a file, and the filename is contained within the JSON-object, so I access it to get the file name and try `unzip()`

```
notice[["all_headers"]][[1]][["headers"]][["content-disposition"]]
[1] "attachment; filename=Doffin-20200709.zip"
unzip("Doffin-200709.zip")Warning message:
In unzip("Doffin-20200709.zip") : error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

So my question is, how do I go about getting the zipped file and unzipping it? The zip file will contain one or more XML-files.

Comment: You could try writing the contents as a binary file and unzipping that: `writeBin(notice$content, "myzip.zip"); unzip("myzip.zip");`

Comment: Afraid that doesn't work, it just creates a zip file that isn't valid

Comment: What does `http::content(notice, "text")` give you?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean httr? 

`> httr::content(notice, "text")
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
[1] "PK\003\004-"`

Comment: That does look like the start of a zip file. Odd that you can't save it is binary and treat it like a normal zip file. Are you able to post the link for testing or is it confidential?

Comment: It’s behind a firewall and with username/password auth I’m afraid.

Comment: Ah well. Without being able to debug, all I can suggest is that you ensure the writeBin call has useBytes = TRUE and that the resulting file can't be opened by your OS. Also ensure the zip file itself isn't password-encrypted

Comment: It has, and it's a file the OS isn't able to open.It's not password protected.